# Magento 2.1 Checkout 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.1 create an order step. **(POST /V1/carts/mine/payment-information)**

[image]

Result:

Array ( [messages] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 500 [message] => Server internal error. See details in report api/630822351214 ) ) ) )

Is the coding wrong?

Comment: check this file `var/report/api/630822351214`

Comment: is the path TEST necessary after rest? try removing it and your script might work.